# Combine Parent Child to one list in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, parent-child

I have

```
public class Parent 
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PartOfRegion { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{  
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

List<Parent> listParent { get; set; } // This list is feed with alot of data and child data to every parent
```

And I want this

```
public class Result
{
    public string Region { get; set;}
    public string PartOfRegion { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

List<Result> resultList = listParent.[LINQ]??
```

So I could make sum on Value depending on Region or PartOfregion and year and so on.

I'm stucked how I can make this Result table with LINQ in C#.

Someone who can give me one direction?

Comment: I don't understand: you have multiple Years/Values, one for each child, and you only want to return one for each parent, is that it? Or group by year?

Comment: @RicardoPeres I think he needs Cartesian product, flattening the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SelectMany` to generate all combinations from the Parent.

Sample code:

```
using System;


List<Parent> listParent = new List<Parent> { new Parent { Region = "a",
    Children = new List<Child> { new Child() { Value = "va" }, new Child() { Value = "vaa" } } }, new Parent { Region = "b",
    Children = new List<Child> { new Child() { Value = "vb" }, new Child() { Value = "vbb" } } }};


List<Result> results = listParent.SelectMany(o=> o.Children.Select(c=> new Result { Value = c.Value, Region = o.Region })).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("");
public class Parent
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PartOfRegion { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string PartOfRegion { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For transform the List into a List you can use LINQs SelectMany operator. You can use a code like that:

```
List<Result> resultList = listParent.SelectMany(parent =>
    parent.Childs.Select(child =>
        new Result {
            Region = parent.Region,
            PartOfRegion = parent.PartOfRegion,
            Type = parent.Type,
            Year = child.Year,
            Value = child.Value
        }
    )
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, .SelectMany is what I'm looking for. I tried that before but must have done something wrong, now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You would typically write a LINQ statement to do whatever you need to do, but the query would depend on what exactly it is you need .

For example, if you want the sum of the values for each child by region you would write

```
listParent.GroupBy(p => p.Region)
  .Select(group => new {
      Region = group.Key, 
      Sum = group.SelectMany(p => p.Childs).Sum(c => c.Value)});
```

But the overall approach is to take the original list and apply linq operators to transform it into whatever we want. It can be difficult to know exactly what operators to use, but there are a bunch of questions for the most common cases here on StackOverflow. And if you cannot find anything relevant, it might be more useful to ask a more specific question for your particular query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want group by `Region`, `PartOfRegion`, `Type` and `Year` (from Child) first you have to flatten the `listParent`, then group and then create the `List<Result>`:

```
List<Result> resultList = listParent.SelectMany(parent => parent.Childs.Select(child => new
{
    Region = parent.Region,
    PartOfRegion = parent.PartOfRegion,
    Type = parent.Type,
    Year = child.Year,
    Value = child.Value
}))
.GroupBy(item => new { item.Region, item.PartOfRegion, item.Type, item.Year })
.Select(group => new Result()
{
    Region = group.Key.Region,
    PartOfRegion = group.Key.PartOfRegion,
    Type = group.Key.Type,
    Year = group.Key.Year,
    Value = group.Sum(item => item.Value)
})
.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, .SelectMany is what I'm looking for.  I tried that before but must have done something wrong, now it works!